# No Delay in Notification for Task Expiration in Android To-Do List App

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications

**Question:**
I want to set a notification for each item in my to-do list when it is about to expire in the next 5 minutes or before 5 minutes of the expiration time. However, in the current implementation, the notification is showing instantly after adding a task to the to-do list. How can I prevent this error?

*example : Current time is 6:00 pm expiration time is 6:30 pm , so the notification should appear at 6:25 pm even if the app is closed.*

But notification is Appearing at instant adding the task , like if its expiration time is very far still swoing notification expired.

Please Give Suggestions to fix this issue.

Here is My Impelementation Logic

**NotificationWroker Class**

package com.example.todolist
//imports

class NotificationWorker(
private val context: Context,
workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(context, workerParams) {

```
override fun doWork(): Result {
    // Retrieve the task details from input data
    val taskId = inputData.getLong("taskId", -1)
    val taskName = inputData.getString("taskName")
    val expirationTime = inputData.getString("expirationTime")

    // Check if the app has the required permission to post notifications
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        // Permission not granted, handle the situation (e.g., show a message or request permission)
        // You can implement your own logic here based on your app's requirements
        // For example, you can show a message to the user or request the permission
        // using a dialog or an in-app prompt.
        // Remember to handle the permission request response as well.
        return Result.failure()
    }

    // Create the notification channel if it doesn't exist
    createNotificationChannel()

    // Create the notification
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("Task Expired")
        .setContentText("Task '$taskName' has expired!")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bar_icon)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .build()

    // Show the notification
    val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
    notificationManager.notify(taskId.toInt(), notification)

    return Result.success()
}

private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID,
            "Task Notifications",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
        channel.description = "Channel for task notifications"

        val notificationManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}

companion object {
    private const val CHANNEL_ID = "task_notification_channel"
}
```

}

**MainActivity Code(Only the Required Portion)**

addSaveBtn.setOnClickListener {

```
            //edit task
            if (et_item.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                id++
                var taskName = et_item.text.toString()
                var category = categorySelected
                if (time_tv.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    var time = time_tv.text.toString()
                    var format = SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d, yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
                    var date = format.format(Date())
                    val todo = TodoData(
                        id,
                        taskName,
                        false,
                        time,
                        date,
                        category,
                        isExpired = false,
                        isNotified = false
                    )
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                            todoDao.insert(todo)
                        }
                       //scheduleLing
                        scheduleNotification(id,taskName,time)
                    }

                    todoList.add(todo)
                    Log.i("Add", "$todo")
                    todoAdapter.notifyItemInserted(todoList.size)
                    bottomDialog.dismiss()
                    emptyImg = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
                    if (todoList.size == 0)
                        emptyImg.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    else
                        emptyImg.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                } else {
                    val snackBar = Snackbar.make(
                        addTaskLl, "Please Select Due Time!",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).setAction("Action", null)
                    snackBar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                    val snackBarView = snackBar.view
                    snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
                    val textView =
                        snackBarView.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                    snackBar.show()
                }

            } else {
                val snackBar = Snackbar.make(
                    addTaskLl, "Task item Can't be Empty!",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                ).setAction("Action", null)
                snackBar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                val snackBarView = snackBar.view
                snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
                val textView =
                    snackBarView.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                snackBar.show()
            }

        }
        // bottomDialog.setCancelable(false)
        bottomDialog.setContentView(view)

        bottomDialog.show()
    }

}
```

**Scheduling Function (present in the MainActivity Class)**

```
private fun scheduleNotification(taskId: Long, taskName: String, expirationTime: String) {
    val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)

    // Parse the expiration time string to a Date object
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
    val expirationDate = format.parse(expirationTime)

    // Calculate the delay before showing the notification (5 minutes)
    val notificationDelay = 5 * 60 * 1000 // 5 minutes in milliseconds

    // Calculate the expiration time in milliseconds
    val expirationMillis = expirationDate?.time ?: return

    // Calculate the notification time by subtracting the delay from the expiration time
    val notificationTime = expirationMillis - notificationDelay

    // Build the input data
    val inputData = Data.Builder()
        .putLong("taskId", taskId)
        .putString("taskName", taskName)
        .build()

    // Create a OneTimeWorkRequest with input data and delay
    val notificationWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationWorker>()
        .setInputData(inputData)
        .setInitialDelay(notificationTime - System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build()

    // Enqueue the work request with a unique tag
    workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(
        "notification_$taskId",
        ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
        notificationWorkRequest
    )
}
```

Except those Two more Functions are Implemented in Adapter Class to Cancel the Notification for the item which is expired or deleted.